# Network Unclaimed on 1025-intel-iotg

Tags: networking, drivers

I am trying to install Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 of intel-IoT. Initially it is loaded with 1016-intel-iotg, but my requirement is 1025-intel-itog. I downloaded the package from [https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-image-5.15.0-1025-intel-iotg_5.15.0-1025.30~20.04.1_amd64.deb.html](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/linux-image-5.15.0-1025-intel-iotg_5.15.0-1025.30%7E20.04.1_amd64.deb.html). After installing this package my network is totally out. Even the wired connections selection is not visible in the settings. When I tried `lshw -C network` it is showing `network UNCLAIMED`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status` I suspect that you are missing several dependencies. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your support. It means a lot to me